# Wireless Network Connection - Limited or no connectivity

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, thinkpad

PC: Thinkpad T42. running Windows XP Pro SP3, fresh install.

I had problems with my connection dropping out repeatedly on one laptop, so I just reinstalled XP. After installing the wireless driver and attempting to connect to the router, I get "Limited or no connectivity".  I have one laptop connected to that router on static IP, and one on "obtain automatically". They both work fine.  I would like this (third) "problem laptop" also to be on automatic IP.

Running IPconfig on the one currently working on automatic shows:

```
IP:       192.168.1.17
Subnet:   255.255.255.0
Gateway:  192.168.1.254
```

The one which currently has a problem shows:

```
IP:       169.254.85.202
Subnet:   255.255.0.0
Gateway:
```

Then I run the network setup wizard choosing "This computer connects to the Internet directly or through a network hub". After restart, ipconfig shows exactly the same thing and problem persists.

Please advice, what what do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt #1:
Ensure that your credentials are typed in correctly.

Attempt #2:
Use some a good wireless network tool (such as Lenovo Internet Connection) and try to connect to the access point from that. (Mabey there is a problem with the user understanding Windows Wireless Management tool or there is a problem with the Windows Wireless Management tool)

Attempt #3
Right-click on My Network Places and go to properties. You should now see a screen that has items on it such as Wireless Network Connection, Local Area Connection, etc. Right click on the Wireless Network Connect, and click properties. Double click on Internet Protocol Version 4 or something among those line. It might also say TCP/IP v4. Make sure that both both of the options are set to automatically obtain.

Good Luck-

Comment: omg.. #1: I had used the Ascii key, instead of the Hex Key. I thought they should both work, but seems not. At least it works with Hex key. Maybe cause the Ascii key starts with a space it messes things up, idk.  thanks!

Comment: No problem! :) Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

The problemn PC is not getting an IP address from the DHCP server so there could be several issues. The fact that it has the APIPA 169.x.X.X address indicates a problem getting an address

Is the wireless card using the corrct driver?  Lenovo has a tool to check this and it works well.

Are you iusing Windows or the Lenovo tool to manage the wireless connection? Does the app see the wireless access point?

Is the adapater set to automatically get an IP?

What happens if you set the problem system using an available IP like 192.168.1.18 or whatever is free and set the gatewayy as indicated at 192.168.1.254  You will likley need to maually set DNS as well.

Check the router to assure it has enough addresses in the pool If it only has a couple or they are all in use for some reason (long lease times and many connections) you may ahve issues

Comment: He will also need to manually set the subnet mask. (in the 5th paragraph)

Comment: @David- If XP or newer, the system populates the subnet mask with the appropriate one (255.255.255.0) when the IP addresses listed are entered. It would ave to be maually set if it was say 255.255.255.252 for some reason

Comment: Wow, I must have never noticed that. Thanks for the info. You learn something new everyday.

Comment: That's why we are here.  Many brains better than one :-)